# Docker different volume path for specific container

Tags: docker, docker-volume

By default docker uses /var/lib/docker/volumes/ for any started container.

Is there any way to launch a new container and have it consume all the required disk on a different specified path on the host?

Basically have the root volume different.

Answer (score 0):

For a specific container only, the simplest way i think would be to use docker volumes, Create docker volume and then attach the volume to the container. So the process running on the container uses up the share, so this is using the disk you would like to use.

More information on the following webpage,
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Answer (score 0):

you can define the volume path.

```
docker run -it --rm -v PWD$:/MyVolume ubuntu bash
```

This command will use the current folder where you execute the command from.
In the container you'll find your file under /MyVolume.

```
jens@DESKTOP:~$ docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:/MyVolume ubuntu bash
root@71969d68099e:/# cd /MyVolume/
root@71969d68099e:/MyVolume# ls
```

But you can define any path:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /home/someuser/somevolumepath:/MyVolume ubuntu bash
```

Almost the same is available in docker compose.

```
  ports:
      - "80:8080"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - $HOME/userhome/https_cert:/etc/nginx/certs
```

Jens